# android fragment binding lost when menu is opened

Tags: android, fragment

I have an *`Activity`* called `MianActivity` that shows a *`Fragment`* named `mainScreenFragment`. The `mainScreenFragment` has a *button*. As soon as I open the menu in the `MianActivity`, a list is shown in an *`AlertDialog`*. Pressing an item in the list should change the text in the button.
In my `mainScreenFragment`.java I wrote:

```
private Button mybutton;

public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mybutton = (Button) binding.myButton;

        mybutton .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG,"mybutton button pressed");                
            }
        });
}

void updateButtonText(String newTxt)
{
    mybutton.setText(newTxt);
}
```

In the MainActivity.java, handling the alertdialog item click event I wrote:

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) view;
            String selectedName = tv.getText().toString();
            mainScreenFragment.updateButtonText(selectedName);
         }
    };
```

But the mybutton.setText(newTxt); gives an null pointer exception. How could that happen?

Comment: Your button or textview could be *null*.

Comment: make sure you are using same instance of `mainScreenFragment`

Comment: private static Button mybutton; did the trick.